# Bind9 failed: permission denied for Debian 11.1

Tags: bind

After installed bind9 for Debian 11.1 and preconfigured I have this information after restart bind:

```
example.local/IN: loading from master file /var/named/example.local.zone failed: permission denied
```

When I move file example.local.zone to /etc/bind9 and after change file location in named.conf.local then everything is OK.

Of course my permission for /var/named is OK and user/group: root:bind. Even if I give full permission then is the same error. Where is problem ?

Comment: Why do you want to load `example.local.zone`? As suggested by filename it's an example.

Comment: I think that newer version bind9 does not allow to create zones outside /etc/bind directory.

Comment: wrongly. i use the latest version and use /var/named

Comment: please show `ls -la /var |grep named` and `ls -la /var/named`

Answer (score 1):

When this happened to me, it was because apparmor was active, and doesn't allow access to paths which aren't alllowlisted. You can probably see the profile at `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named` to confirm. I'd suggest either moving your files to `/etc/bind` or `/var/lib/bind`, or update the apparmor profile to include `/var/named`.

Comment: thank you! this worked